# Weird sign next to folder icons

Tags: windows

[image]

As on the picture. You can see the sign on the left side. Any idea what could it be?

Comment: It looks like some type of application is performing folder backup and/or synchronization.  Do you have that type of software installed?  If you still aren't quite sure, can you post another picture that is a bit larger (higher resolution)?

Comment: I don't have any such program installed, at least to my knowledge. Sorry but I don't have a higher res version. The icons have disappeared on another explorer window which I've opened

Comment: I tried a Google reverse image search, but it couldn't find anything that matched.  As I said, based upon the way it looks it would seem to be some type of backup and/or synchronization function.  You should double-check your list of installed programs, and perhaps even scrutinize [Windows event logs](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/using-windows-admin-tools-like-a-pro/lesson3/) to see if anything pertinent is listed around the time you saw those icons.

Comment: Windows OneDrive is listed as installed today in the programs list. It has been installed since forever though and I never used it in hte past.

Comment: I noticed that these icons appeared when I changed my screen res to a very high one. I tried to recreate it to no avail

Comment: That might have been a coincidence.  Again, it may be prudent to take a look at your Windows event logs to see if anything appears corresponding to the time that it happened.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50626/discussion-between-keklord-and-run5k).

Comment: My apologies, but apparently the Stack Exchange chat client is blocked on my domain here at work.

Comment: Not a problem. http://sendvid.com/3kl0sk10

Please check this video out when you have time. I recorded this with ShadowPlay when it happened. I am not sure if it will help or not but it may shed some light

Comment: I'm afraid that site is blocked on my work domain, also.  Forgive me for sounding repetitive, but have you taken the time to look through your Windows event logs (both System and Application) to see if there are any noteworthy entries around the time that it occurred?

Comment: I did check the Event Viewer and didn't find anything interesting at the time of when it happened. Just some defrags being done and that's about it. I actually already mentioned that in the chat but I didn't know that the domain is blocked on your work domain.

Comment: I'm sorry that I couldn't help out a bit more, but hopefully someone else can chime in who might actually recognize it.